# There is no .xib file when I create a new "Empty Application" in XCode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I am working through the Big Nerd Ranch Guide (2nd Ed) for iOS Programming using Xcode version 4.2.

For the very first project I'm asked to create a new project which is a "Window-based Application" the description for which reads "This template provides a starting point for any application.  It provides just an application delegate and a window".  The "Window-based Application" option was not available to me in XCode 4.2 but I did see the option to create a "New Empty Application" which has the same description ("This template provides a starting point for any application.  It provides just an application delegate and a window")

When I create the project I'm supposed to have a MainWindow.xib file but that does not show up at all in my project?  Help please

Comment: Did you try the search field in Xcode?

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? Xcode 4.2 empty application template is the best thing that happened to Xcode since...ever. It creates a window programmatically and I honestly suggest you don't waste device resources by creating a .xib file just for the window. If you have trouble understanding programmatically creating a window, ask a new question.

Answer (score 11):

When you create the project, don't forget to uncheck the option "storyboard". Once you uncheck it, you can see the xib files.

Comment: Where is this uncheck option "storyboard" when a new Project is created with Single Application

Answer (score 5):

I am using the same book, had the same problem but I figured how to fix it.

1. Create a new xib file by

right click Quiz folder -> New File -> iOS -> User Interface -> Window -> click Next

1. click the Window.xib file then find an Object and drag it under Objects -> select the third tab on the right -> change this class to AppDelegate

click File's Owner -> change this class to UIApplication -> click the 6th tab and connect delegate to Window

1. goto AppDelegate.h and put IBOutlet in front of UIWindow *window;

goto Window.xib again and connect window under Outlets to Window.

Also in plist file add a row
key - Main nib file base name
type - string
value - mainwindow

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a MainWindow.xib afterwards:

```
File > New > File >
```

There should be a `Window.xib`. If not, creat an empty .XIB file and drag a window (`UIWindow`) into your Objects pane. Copy the connections as they are displayed in the book.

Hope that helps.

PS.:I recommend to not use beta software to start with iOS

Comment: Storyboard used in lieu in xib file.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a empty project and **do** want to use storyboading, then do:

1. create empty project
2. add new file (storyboard)
3. make sure to add a correct entry in your app-info.plist file. (Just create a simple project with storyboard and look-up the key there in the app-plist).
4. throw a view controller on the board, and off you go.

Like this you have a nice clean project, **with** the use of the storyboard feature.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this in the official Forum to the Book. BNR posted a project that you can use as your default Project for all Chapters in this Book. They created a small Project that looks as if you created an empty project with the XCode version before iOS5 was released.

http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=1817

regards

Thomas