# Cannot find the windows outlet for the Object in iOS

Tags: xcode, ios5

I have been working with Xcode 4.2.1, but following some tutorials and videos from the earlier version of Xcode.

As usual I had the problem with the Windows Based Application. I created a empty application for my Windows Based Application project and was following some steps from the same forum of how to add a MainWindow.xib file to my project using this post

[There is no .xib file when I create a new "Empty Application" in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313150/there-is-no-xib-file-when-i-create-a-new-empty-application-in-xcode)

I also followed one more post which has some good screenshots:
http://www.trappers.tk/site/2011/06/16/mainwindow-xib/

Now my problem is I cannot ctrl+drag of the window outlet from the App Delegate object to the Window object. The reason is I could not find out the window outlet from tze attributes menu. One can see the screenshot of how it is looking in my xcode:

[image: Screenshot from my project]

And below one can see how it should have a windows outlet for the App Delegate.
[image: Actually how it should be looking]

Is there anything I am missing or left something behind before coming there. I followed the steps exactly as mentioned in the above posts. I tried creating new projects just to make sure Im doing everything correct.

Any information regarding this would be appreciated.

Thanks 
Raaks

Comment: from the screenshot it appears..you have to ctrl-drag from window to window in the attributes inspector...is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: yes exactly thats what I want to achieve but as you could see I cannot find the windows outlet under AppDelegate attribute!

Comment: there is one above it?in your screenshot..

Comment: I cant find anything above Referencing Outlets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your tutorial..

http://www.trappers.tk/site/2011/06/16/mainwindow-xib/

The answer to your problem is Simple(and also this is the way you should do most of the time in future..)

**1) Click on File's Owner(In the placeholder section..left to the xib).**

**2) In the attributes section you will see a window Outlet..**

**3) Drag window from the attributes section(right click-drag or ctrl-drag.) and drop it on window in Objects window..(left to the xib)**

Comment: I got your point how to drag and drop, but still in the connections inspector for the App Delegate I could not get the option Delagate-windows which I need to drag and drop it on the window in the placeholder section

Comment: sure I can to chat in which room are you active